# Reading file as stream of strings in Dart: how many events will be emitted?

Tags: dart

Standard way to open a file in Dart as a stream is to use `file.openRead()` which returns a `Stream<List<int>>`.

The next standard step is to transform this stream with `utf8.decoder` `SteamTranformer` which returns `Stream<String>`.

I noticed that with the files I've tried this resulting stream only emits a single event with the whole file content represented as one string. But I feel like this should not be a general case since otherwise the API wouldn't need to return a stream of strings, a `Future<String>` would suffice.

Could you explain how can I observe the behavior when this stream emits more than one event? Is this dependent on the file size / disk IO rate / some buffers size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on file size and buffer size, and however the file operations are implemented.

If you read a large file, you will very likely get multiple events of a limited size. The UTF-8 decoder decodes chunks eagerly, so you should get roughly the same number of chunks after decoding. It might carry a few bytes across chunk boundaries, but the rest of the bytes are decoded as soon as possible.

Checking on my local machine, the buffer size seems to be 65536 bytes. Reading a file larger than that gives me multiple chunks.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried with bigger files and it produces multiple chunks.

Comment: On my local machine, the buffer size was also 65536 bytes. Is it the platform implementation that determines the buffer size or is it Dart?